# What is a Software to handle large amount of google form responses

Tags: database, data-analysis, forms, spreadsheet

I have a google response form that is connected to a Google sheet. However, due to the large volume of responses the spreadsheet is running too slow to open and operate within. I think the spreadsheet is about to reach the cell limit so I might need to use other software to handle the large volume of responses coming in.

What should I use to better use and analyze the responses that are there and coming in?

I have heard that using Bigquery might be a good option but if I load the data for incoming responses from the sheet into bigquery won't the spreadsheet still remain full and not accept any more form submissions once it's full? Or is there a way that any form responses that are received are loaded automatically into bigquery and deleted from the spreadsheet so that the spreadsheet does not fill up?

Or is there a better way to deal with this apart from bigquery? Would I need to move on to something like an actual database?
However, I still need to be able to receive the responses from the Google form though.

Comment: Yes, you need a database. BTW, how the users fill up the Google Sheet? What form are they using? Google Form?

Comment: Yes, they are using Google forms that feed into a google sheet